# The security group 'gettingstartedgroup' does not exist

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to learn Amazon AWS. I ran their tutorial package-"GettingStartedApp.java" after setting my access id and access key in the property file. But I see this exception.

```
Caught Exception: The security group 'gettingstartedgroup' does not exist
Reponse Status Code: 400
Error Code: InvalidGroup.NotFound
```

How should I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to use the string `"gettingstartedgroup"` as a security group.

If you just created your EC2 AWS instance, then you either add a security group with that name or use the `default` one. 
For the latter, just **change** from `gettingstartedgroup` to `default`.

Answer (score 0):

At first, please execute CreateSecurityGroupApp.java and then GettingStartedGroup will be creataed in Oregon region.